# Return a row with count of 0 when GROUP BY yields no matches

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Trying to write a query in MySQL that takes 4 different actions performed by a specific `deviceToken` and within a specific timeframe and returns the `action`, the `deviceToken`, and the `count` of how many times that action was taken. My problem is, in order to handle the result properly, I always need all 4 actions to be a part of the return, even if the count is 0, and `GROUP BY` notoriously does not play along with that. Here is the query I have currently:

```
SELECT `action`, 
       deviceToken, 
       CASE WHEN `action` = 'calendar' THEN COUNT(*) END AS CalCount,
       CASE WHEN `action` = 'closinginfo' THEN COUNT(*) END AS CloseingCount,
       CASE WHEN `action` = 'generalinfo' THEN COUNT(*) END AS GenInfoCount,
       CASE WHEN `action` = 'login' THEN COUNT(*) END AS LoginCount   
FROM `action`
WHERE deviceToken = '44262f82-3767-49c8-8786-ee377ea00a64'
    AND (`action` = 'login' OR `action` = 'calendar' OR `action` = 'closinginfo' OR `action` = 'generalinfo')
    AND `timestamp` > CONCAT(DATE(NOW()),' 23:59:59') - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+14 DAY
    AND `timestamp` < CONCAT(DATE(NOW()),' 23:59:59') - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+7 DAY
GROUP BY `action`
```

For a `deviceToken` that has performed all 4 actions within that time frame, the result looks like this:

[image]

The way my client handles this result is already perfect. However, a `deviceToken` that has taken less than all 4 actions looks like this:

[image]

What I need to have for my data handling to work universally is those missing rows still returned, but just list those counts as 0. Does anyone have any idea of how to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you really need the counts for different actions in different columns, when you have the action in the first column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql boolean expressions resolve to 1 or 0 so you can `SUM` them:

```
SELECT  
       SUM(`action` = 'calendar') AS CalCount,
       SUM(`action` = 'closinginfo') AS CloseingCount,
       SUM(`action` = 'generalinfo') AS GenInfoCount,
       SUM(`action` = 'login') AS LoginCount   
FROM `action`
WHERE deviceToken = '44262f82-3767-49c8-8786-ee377ea00a64'
    AND (`action` = 'login' OR `action` = 'calendar' OR `action` = 'closinginfo' OR `action` = 'generalinfo')
    AND `timestamp` > CONCAT(DATE(NOW()),' 23:59:59') - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+14 DAY
    AND `timestamp` < CONCAT(DATE(NOW()),' 23:59:59') - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+7 DAY
```

Note that this query doesn't use a `GROUP BY` and only aggregates are in the `SELECT`

Comment: This generates an error for me. `FUNCTION analytics.SUM does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual`

Comment: Ah okay, it was just a syntax thing. Can't be a blank space before the parentheses of a function for MySQL. All set, this solution is elegant and works very well, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` with a table that lists all the actions to get null values for those rows.

```
SELECT t1.`action`, 
       '44262f82-3767-49c8-8786-ee377ea00a64' AS deviceToken, 
       CASE WHEN t1.`action` = 'calendar' THEN COUNT(a.action) END AS CalCount,
       CASE WHEN t1.`action` = 'closinginfo' THEN COUNT(a.action) END AS CloseingCount,
       CASE WHEN t1.`action` = 'generalinfo' THEN COUNT(a.action) END AS GenInfoCount,
       CASE WHEN t1.`action` = 'login' THEN COUNT(a.action) END AS LoginCount
FROM (SELECT 'calendar' AS action
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'closinginfo'
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT 'generalinfo'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'login') AS t1
LEFT JOIN `action` AS a
ON a.action = t1.action
    AND deviceToken = '44262f82-3767-49c8-8786-ee377ea00a64'
    AND `timestamp` > CONCAT(DATE(NOW()),' 23:59:59') - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+14 DAY
    AND `timestamp` < CONCAT(DATE(NOW()),' 23:59:59') - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+7 DAY
GROUP BY t1.`action`
```

Comment: This is causing those three row that normally aren't returned to show up, but instead of the count being 0, the count is 1

Comment: Yeah, need to change `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(a.action)`. You have to count a column in the `a` table so that the rows with null matches aren't counted.